# trouble unzipping file under Windows

Tags: r, unzip

I have the following code:

```
download.file(
"http://www.wikipathways.org//wpi/batchDownload.php?species=Homo%20sapiens&fileType=txt",
  destfile="human.zip")
files <- unzip( "human.zip", list=T)
```

It works on Linux, but throws the following error on Windows:

```
Error in unzip("human.zip", list = T) : 
  error -103 with zipfile in unzGetCurrentFileInfo
```

Do you happen to know what's the problem?

Comment: According to ?unzip, "unzip 
The method to be used. An alternative is to use getOption("unzip"), which on a Unix-alike may be set to the path to a unzip program."  So, do you have unzip on your windows box and are your paths set?

Comment: Trouble is, I don't have a Windows box. I was checking my package with the winbuilder service. However, unzGetCurrentFileInfo seems to be a function in the unzip program, so the answer is "probably yes".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `?download.file`, we read that:

> If `mode` is not supplied and url ends in one of .gz, .bz2, .xz, .tgz,
>   .zip, .rda or .RData a binary transfer is done. Since Windows (unlike
>   Unix-alikes) does distinguish between text and binary files, care is
>   needed that other binary file types are transferred with mode = "wb".

Note that this list does not include `.zip`, although it *is* a binary file type. So you need to pass `mode="wb"`.

I cannot reproduce your example, but it solved my identical problem.  Here is an example:

```
url <- "https://www.bls.gov/cex/pumd/ce_pumd_interview_diary_dictionary.xlsx"

download.file(url, 'file1.xlsx')              

download.file(url, 'file2.xlsx', mode="wb")   # Try this instead

library(readxl)

read_xlsx('file1.xlsx', sheet='Variables')    # Fails
# Error in sheets_fun(path) : 
#   Evaluation error: error -103 with zipfile in unzGetCurrentFileInfo

read_xlsx('file2.xlsx', sheet='Variables')    # Works
# A tibble: 3,580 x 13
```