# error -103 with zipfile in unzGetCurrentFileInfo

Tags: r, unzip

I am reading the names of the files inside a zip archive through R with

```
unzip(myzip, list=TRUE)$Name
```

But I get an error:

> Error in unzip(myzip, list = TRUE) :
> error -103 with zipfile in unzGetCurrentFileInfo

Any idea what might be going on?

### Extra info

- Sorry I am unable to provide a reproducible example at the moment. I tried zipping again the first few files of the zip and it works correctly.
- The zip is ~ 8Gb, 100+ Gb if unzipped.
- It does not seem to be OS-specific. I get the same error on Mac and Windows. It is also not dependent on where the zip was created, I tried creating a zip of the first few files from a Mac or a Windows, and both run correctly.
- I have two zip like this (zipped on different computers) and both throw an error, so it does not seem to be a random data corruption or something like this.
- If I am reading correctly `?unzip`, it does not sound related to the size of my zip archive (8+ Gb). My zip contains ~ 3,000 files of ~ 30 Mb each, while unzip seems to have a problem with single files > 4 Gb pre-compression. From `?unzip`:

> [does not support..] >= 4GB files pre-compression contained in a zip file: like many builds of unzip it may truncate these, in R's case with a warning if possible

Any clues?

Comment: Seem sto be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892505/trouble-unzipping-file-under-windows

Comment: No, it's the same error message but different context