# download.file only downloading partial zip files in R

Tags: r, unzip, r-unz

I'm downloading a zip file with multiple files inside it using:

```
https://www.find-school-performance-data.service.gov.uk/download-data?download=true&regions=0&filters=GIAS,KS4PROV,KS4SUBJECTENTRIES&fileformat=xls&year=2021-2022&meta=false
```

This returns a zip file with the following structure:

```
> 2021-2022
   > england_school_information.xlsx
   > england_ks4provisional.xlsx
   > england_ks4-subject-entries.xlsx
```

When I run exactly the same URL string through R, it downloads an incomplete file:

```
web <-"https://www.find-school-performance-data.service.gov.uk/download-data?download=true&regions=0&filters=GIAS,KS4PROV,KS4SUBJECTENTRIES&fileformat=xls&year=2021-2022&meta=false"
temp <- tempfile()
download.file(web, temp)

unzip(temp, list = TRUE)
```

> Error in unzip(temp, list = TRUE) :
> error -103 with zipfile in unzGetCurrentFileInfo

Looking at the file in `temp`, the structure is only:

```
> 2021-2022
   > england_school_information.xlsx
```

Comment: Consider increasing `options(timeout = 3600)`

Comment: it does seem to be downloading the file, sadly timeout makes no difference

Comment: Ah, found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892505/trouble-unzipping-file-under-windows which seems to help. Running `download.file(web, temp, mode="wb")` fixes things